# Unit testing Nativescript application logic on a browser

Tags: unit-testing, angular-cli, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to set up unit testing for a Nativescript application, run by `ng test` on a browser. The problem is that whenever there is a `tns-core-modules` or another plugin import, the module cannot be resolved because of the platform specific files (e.g. "tns-core-modules/application/application.android.js") that never get compiled into the bundle, thus throwing an error like "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tns-core-modules/application'".

I know there is a built-in unit test support in Nativescript. The problem I have with it is that it can't run on CI. I would like to be a ble to have lightweight tests for my business logic, mocking out all platform dependencies.
I have looked for a way to mock the module imports at runtime with no luck. I looked into `rewire` package but it only runs on node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. Not a very elegant solution and I have yet to see how much maintenance it requires. Key points here:

1. Use `paths` section of the `tsconfig.json` to add mock import
   locations
2. In the mocks directory create files for any unresolved module
3. Some nativescript modules are referencing helper functions on global
   scope but they're undefined. My solution was to define them in
   `test.ts` like this

```
window['__decorate'] = () => {};
window['__extends'] = () => {};
window['__metadata'] = () => {};
window['__param'] = () => {};
window['layout_base_1'] = { CSSType: () => {} };
window['Crashlytics'] = {};
window['Fabric'] = {};
```

Comment: do you still use this solution, or did you find something more reliable maybe?

Comment: @ForestG I'm still using this solution. It works quite well and there isn't that much overhead once the initial work is done.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not run NativeScript application on Browser.

In case if you are looking for something like headless mode, [Appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) has one too, `isHeadless` in capabilities.

Between, may I know why you think you can not run the {N} unit tests on CI? It should work on CI too, after all it's a machine that runs the same commands based on some trigger.

Comment: 1. While it is not possible to run the whole app on a browser, it is definitely possible to run isolated javascript with mocked dependencies. My goal is to test the business logic (not components, not the native integration). I have succeeded doing it and will post an accepted answer when I'm finished.
2. Appium is for e2e, not unit testing
3. Android emulators can't run on Travis CI, only iOS. I also saw some issues with TestBed then I decided this is not good enough for me.