# Unit testing in browser for NativeScript fails because of .tns. files

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, nativescript

I have an Angular flavoured Nativescript project, which must be tested with "vanila" Jasmine, in a browser (so not in mobile) with `ng test`.

By default, with "naked" tests, it works. But the problem is, if I try to test/import anything, that has a ".tns" alternative, in some cases it loads that, and the build fails.

My problem is similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458902/unit-testing-nativescript-application-logic-on-a-browser) but there were no good solution described there.

So for instance:
I have two files:

```
app.component.tns.ts
app.component.ts
```

and I try to import it for testing in `app.component.spec.ts`:

```
import {AppComponent} from "@src/app/app.component";
```

it loads the `.tns.` file, and the build fails, as it cannot load the mobile-specific libraries.

```
     ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.tns.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer' in '/home/..../src/app'
resolve 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer' in '/home/...../src/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/...../src/package.json (relative path: ./app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module

    ...
     @ ./src/app/app.component.tns.ts 25:35-72
     @ ./src/app/app.module.spec.ts
     @ ./src sync \.spec\.ts$
     @ ./src/test.ts
```

is there any solution to "remove" the .tns. files, just as if I were running a simple ng serve?

**update**: My `tsconfig.spec.json` should exclude these files, but it does not work either ...

```
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.tns.ts",
    "**/*.android.ts",
    "**/*.ios.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the problem was with **tsconfig.json**. Specificly this part:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
      "paths": {
          "@src/*": [
              "src/*.android.ts",
              "src/*.ios.ts",
              "src/*.tns.ts",
              "src/*.web.ts",
              "src/*.ts"
          ]
      },
```

As this was extended by the tsconfig.spec.json.

I modified the **tsconfig.spec.json** to this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2015.iterable"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*.ts"
      ]
    },
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.tns.ts",
    "**/*.android.ts",
    "**/*.ios.ts"
  ]
}
```

and now the tests run, and the correct components are imported.